# Div class does not style like the css

Tags: html, css

My css

```
.title {
font-size:20pt;
font-weight:700;
}
```

My html

```
<div class="title">Some word</div>
```

But "Some word" won't style like I put in css (size 20pt, weight 700)

If I style right in the div

```
<div style="font-size:20pt;font-weight:700">Some word</div>
```

And it actually style it, but using css it won't style, so what is the problem?

Here is some image
CSS
[i.stack.imgur.com/FG9C9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG9C9.png)

index.php link the correct `my-app.css` directory
[i.stack.imgur.com/LaUSj.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaUSj.jpg)

Div class "iostitle" like in css
[i.stack.imgur.com/jp3oW.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp3oW.jpg)

But no style
[i.stack.imgur.com/V3n02.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3n02.png)

Comment: Does any of the css work? Maybe the file is not being linked correctly.

Comment: Weird thing is this class won't work, other style work normally, btw i'm using framework7 on php

Comment: You should provide more information. Maybe your css class rules are overwritten by another style.

Comment: No style overide the div, just div and class

Comment: The HTML and CSS you provided works https://jsfiddle.net/d1odtdg2/, for us to be able to help please supply a reproducible example.

Comment: My project: go to qa.ftios.net, go to Firmware tab>iOS 10>10.2 image, you will see the TV is styled by styling directly to the div, other header is still remain unstyled even though the class is accurate

Comment: @superquanganh Please provide a reproducible example in the question itself as it needs to be self contained - as soon as the issue is fixed on your website this question would lose relevance. You'll often find that the act of reproducing the issue in a Stack Snippet will show you where the issue lies.

Comment: If this css works (as shown in few fiddle examples), and the rest of your css works (so you are accessing css correctly), and it works as inline style, then the only problem I can think of is that your css is overwritten by another rule(s). You can try adding !important to test this (even though it might still not work).

Comment: Check my image in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your images. I also wondered why the class `.iostitle` not recognized while the class below it `.iosdesc` is working correctly.

Maybe you need to force the `div` selector in front of the class like

```
div.iostitle {
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

See if that's help

Comment: I opened your site again and worked here [link](http://i.imgur.com/OOTSzUr.png) .Don't forget to hard refresh your browser because the css is cached.